# Error while cross compiling using crosstool-ng. How to debug?

Tags: cross-compilation

This is my build log:

```
[ERROR]     
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing C library headers & start files'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@172]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_backend_once[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@347]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_backend[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@143]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_start_files[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@60]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@598]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/powerpc-eabi/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.15.2/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 29:41.80)
```

I want to build a kernel after cross compiling that should work on a 32 bit machine. I am working on an amd64 bit and on a 32 bit Ubuntu os. What should my crosstool configuration file be to get this to work?

Comment: What did you do to prompt this message? Was it `make install` by any chance?

Comment: So, post the content of `build.log`.

Answer (score 1):

It failed while  "Installing C library headers & start files". My guess would be that you don't have permissions to wherever the build is trying to copy something to.

Comment: I did a ct-nf build in my crosstool.